# Regex to get GUID or Error from a response stream

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble creating a Regex to match either a GUID or an error message from a response stream.

For example, the response is either:

```
{ "uuid": "8e5b0721-26c4-11df-b354-002170de47d3" }
```

or

```
{ "error": "<--Error Message-->" }
```

I have the Regex for a GUID:

`new Regex(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$"`

But I'm not entirely sure that the response will always be a GUID.

I guess I'm looking for a GUID that will return a the contents of the second set of quotation marks regardless of type.

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` signs afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a json format string.

Instead of using regex to get the data, use a json parer instead.

Check **[DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)**